# Cakephp 2.x remove automatic created select tags from form helper

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am working on a form and i can't figure out how to disable the select tags that get created automatically.
I am creating an input field that has the name campaign_id. It looks to me that whenever an inputname has something with _id, CakePHP creates selectboxes around the input field.

```
     echo $this->Form->input('campaign_id', array(
                                'label' => __('Campaign ID')
                            ));
```

I tried to chang the name and then it's working. But for the application the name needs to be campaign_id.

is there an option or a way to disable the select tags, so that i can use the input field manually instead of needing to select from a list?

UPDATE:
Thx to Arilia for pointing this out.

Forgot about the option: type => 'text'

Comment: add `'type' => 'text'` in the options array.

Comment: I feel like such a dumbf*ck right now..... haha 
Thx alot for helping me :)